# Lower central series and Euler characteristics of aspherical $2$--complexes

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

Stallings proves the following (remarkable theorem!) using the lower central series. (Homology and central series of groups, p171.)

Suppose $G$ is a group, $K$ a field, with $H_2(G,K)=0$. If $x_1,\dotsc,x_n\in G$ are linearly independent when considered as elements of $H_1(G,K)$, then $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ form the basis of a free subgroup of $G$.

This has the following corollary.

If $G=\pi_1(X)$, $X$ a compact aspherical $2$--complex, $G$ not free, and generated by $n$ elements, then $\chi(G)>1-n$.

Is there a proof of the corollary that doesn't go via the lower central series?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the lower central series?

Comment: Because I want to prove a related theorem where the source is not residually nilpotent and am fishing around for ideas.

Comment: A $n$-generated group $G$ is free (on those $n$ generators) if and only if $\beta_1^{(2)}(G)=n-1$. In any other case it is $\beta_1^{(2)}(G)<n-1$ and hence $\chi(G)>1-n$ if $G$ is $2$-dimensional since $\chi(G)$ is the alternating sum of $\ell^2$-Betti numbers. It's a proof that is not using the lower central series.

Comment: That is quite mercenary.